# Remove a Magento attribute from configurables and associated simple products

Tags: magento, attributes, configurable

I have some configurable products that have many associated simple products, each with many custom options. The configurables use three attributes. My client has now decided that they want to remove one of the attributes. I have used the SQL method to remove one of the attributes, but this is now affecting the custom options when the remaining attributes are selected. The custom options no longer show up. I am assuming this because the attribute is still part of the associated simple products.

Is there a way to remove the attribute from the associated simple products as well, so that the custom options will show correctly when the remaining attributes are chosen?

Answer (score 0):

The attribute, which you are trying to remove is part of each configurable super product, not associated products, as far as I know. Check `'catalog_product_super_attribute'` table in db, remove all rows, which have `'attribute_id'` set to id, which you want to remove.

Clean the cache, reindex and see, if it works.

Comment: I did that for one of the products, and it removes the attribute, but when a selection is made with the remaining attributes on the product page the custom options from the associated simple product do not show up.

Comment: Here's an example: http://www.simplyrooflights.co.uk/contemporary-rooflights-pyramid-rooflights/pyramid-rooflights.html   If you see on this page there are three attributes in the product set and only when you get to the 'glass border colour' option and select the custom options then show up. If I remove the 'glass border colour' attribute none of the custom options show up when selecting options in the remaining two attributes on the product page.

Answer (score 0):

To remove one super product attribute from all configurable products, you could execute this SQL query in the database:

```
DELETE FROM catalog_product_super_attribute WHERE attribute_id = <id>;
```

The table catalog_product_super_attribute links products to super product attributes.